# docking gui to variable active window

Tags: autohotkey

i see alot of examples allowing me to open  a program and use winwait then winexist to dock a gui to it.

instead what i want to do is dock my gui to what ever window is active. ive tried a million ways, please help.

(also when i do get it to attach to a window It doesnt spawn perfectly centered because in the main script when ever i try to do:

```
        WinGetPos cX, cY, cW, cH, ahk_id %ChildhWnd% 
        offset1 := (mw / 2) - (cw /2)
```

it throws an error when i hit the hot key saying x y is not valid

BELOW: a script i didnt completely make on my own. i figured out the math on my own but borrowed heavily from sources i cant remember. it almost does what i need but not quite

````
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
#SingleInstance, force

^T::
hookProcAdr := RegisterCallback("HookProc")
hHook := SetWinEventHook(0x800B,0x800B,0,hookProcAdr,0,0,0) ; EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE 

Gui, +hwndChildhWnd +AlwaysOnTop
Gui, add, text,,some text in a small gui that will move around with a notepad window
Gui, add, Button,,Button

MainhWnd := WinExist() ;<---------what do i do here?

;--------------------------------------------;
;-----i commented my second problem here-----;
;--------------------------------------------;

WinGetPos, mX, mY, mW, mH, ahk_id %MainhWnd%
;WinGetPos cX, cY, cW, cH, ahk_id %ChildhWnd% <--------{why cant i put child window here-+
;                                                                                        |
offset2 := (mw / 2) ; - (cw /2)  <------------------------with offset subtraction here <-+

cX := mX + offset2
cY := mY

Gui, show, x%cX% y%cY%

return

;-------------------;
;-----functions-----;
;-------------------;

HookProc(hWinEventHook, event, hwnd) 
{ 
    global   MainHwnd, ChildhWnd 
    if (hwnd = MainHwnd)
    {
        SetWinDelay, -1
        WinGetPos hX, hY, hW, hH, ahk_id %MainhWnd% 
        WinGetPos cX, cY, cW, cH, ahk_id %ChildhWnd% 
        
        offset1 := (hw / 2) - (cw / 2)
        X := hX + offset1
        Y := hY

        WinMove ahk_id %ChildhWnd%,,X,Y,w%cw%,h%ch%
    }
} 

SetWinEventHook(eventMin, eventMax, hmodWinEventProc, lpfnWinEventProc, idProcess, idThread, dwFlags) { 
   DllCall("CoInitialize", "uint", 0) 
   return DllCall("SetWinEventHook", "uint", eventMin, "uint", eventMax, "uint", hmodWinEventProc, "uint", lpfnWinEventProc, "uint", idProcess, "uint", idThread, "uint", dwFlags) 
}```
````

Comment: also i couldn't figure out how to use dock in this properly so i didnt use i lol .

Comment: I mainly just want to know how to attach a gui to any active window and how to make it so it updates to new active windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few mistakes in there and the window switching part has to be added in with some extra logic & magic.
Also, I'm going to convert this script away from the legacy syntax and use the modern expression syntax instead.

So first, on this line `MainhWnd := WinExist()`.
We want to start off with the currently active window, so lets use `A` [<sup>(docs)</sup>](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ActiveWindow) like so:
`MainhWnd := WinExist("A")`

Then this part of the code:

```
WinGetPos, mX, mY, mW, mH, ahk_id %MainhWnd%
;WinGetPos cX, cY, cW, cH, ahk_id %ChildhWnd% <--------{why cant i put child window here-+
;                                                                                        |
offset2 := (mw / 2) ; - (cw /2)  <------------------------with offset subtraction here <-+

cX := mX + offset2
cY := mY

Gui, show, x%cX% y%cY%
```

Here you can't get the child window's position because it doesn't exist yet.
If the gui is pre-determined, you can just know what its width is going to be.
And if its width doesn't change, there also is no need to get its width every single time a window moves.
So maybe just store the predetermined width in a variable and you're done.

And if the width can't be predetermined, you can for example just quickly show the gui and grab it's width and then move it right away.

```
ChildWindowWidthHalf := 349/2

WinGetPos, mX, mY, mW, , % "ahk_id " MainhWnd
offset2 := (mw / 2) - ChildWindowWidthHalf

cX := mX + offset2
cY := mY

Gui, show, % "x" cX " y" cY
```

Here you can also see the first occurrences of me ditching the legacy syntax and switching over to an [expression](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expressions), for example here concatenating a string with a variable:
`ahk_id %MainhWnd%` → `% "ahk_id " MainhWnd`
Basically a single `%` followed up with a space, forces a command's parameter to evaluate an expression as opposed to expecting a legacy text parameter.
If all this is completely new to you, I recommend checking out [this](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm) page on the documentation.

---

Then onto the problems in the `HookProc` function:

```
HookProc(hWinEventHook, event, hwnd) 
{ 
    global   MainHwnd, ChildhWnd 
    if (hwnd = MainHwnd)
    {
        SetWinDelay, -1
        WinGetPos hX, hY, hW, hH, ahk_id %MainhWnd% 
        WinGetPos cX, cY, cW, cH, ahk_id %ChildhWnd% 
        
        offset1 := (hw / 2) - (cw / 2)
        X := hX + offset1
        Y := hY

        WinMove ahk_id %ChildhWnd%,,X,Y,w%cw%,h%ch%
    }
}
```

First here
`global   MainHwnd, ChildhWnd`
we can ditch the variable `MainHwnd`, since it's of no use to us. We want `MainHwnd` to be the currently active window, not the one window we determined at the start of the script.
And also lets add in this variable `ChildWindowWidthHalf`.

`if (hwnd = MainHwnd)`
This check also makes no sense for us it should be completely removed.
Although, I'd highly recommend replacing it with this `if (hwnd = WinActive("A"))`, so you filter out messages which are unrelated to the currently active window moving.

This this:
`SetWinDelay, -1`
No reason to set that every single time, we can just set it once at the top of the script.

Onto this:

```
WinGetPos hX, hY, hW, hH, ahk_id %MainhWnd% 
WinGetPos cX, cY, cW, cH, ahk_id %ChildhWnd% 
        
offset1 := (hw / 2) - (cw / 2)
```

We are not interested in the `MainhWnd`, as explained above, lets replace it with the hwnd we get straight from the windows message. The hwnd that's passed into the `HookProc` function's 3rd parameter.
`WinGetPos, hX, hY, hW, , % "ahk_id " hwnd`
And then we can get rid of getting the child window's position. It's of no use.
And then lets also switch the offset to use the predetermined child window width again:
`offset1 := (hW / 2) - ChildWindowWidthHalf`

And then onto the [`WinMove` command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm):
`WinMove ahk_id %ChildhWnd%,,X,Y,w%cw%,h%ch%`
It's being used wrong. The width and height parameters don't take a `w` and `h` character in front of them. And there's no reason for us the change the window's width or height anyway. Here's what it should look like:
`WinMove, % "ahk_id " ChildhWnd, , % X, % Y`

---

> And now you should have a *working* script as follows:

```
SetWinDelay, -1

hookProcAdr := RegisterCallback("HookProc")
hHook := SetWinEventHook(0x800B,0x800B,0,hookProcAdr,0,0,0) ; EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE 

Gui, +hwndChildhWnd +AlwaysOnTop
Gui, add, text, , % "some text in a small gui that will move around with a notepad window"
Gui, add, Button, , Button


MainhWnd := WinExist("A")

ChildWindowWidthHalf := 349/2

WinGetPos, mX, mY, mW, , % "ahk_id " MainhWnd
offset2 := (mw / 2) - ChildWindowWidthHalf

cX := mX + offset2
cY := mY

Gui, show, % "x" cX " y" cY
return

HookProc(hWinEventHook, event, hwnd) 
{ 
    global ChildhWnd, ChildWindowWidthHalf
    if (hwnd = WinActive("A"))
    {
        WinGetPos, hX, hY, hW, , % "ahk_id " hwnd 
        
        offset1 := (hW / 2) - ChildWindowWidthHalf
        X := hX + offset1
        Y := hY
        
        WinMove, % "ahk_id " ChildhWnd, , % X, % Y
    }
} 

SetWinEventHook(eventMin, eventMax, hmodWinEventProc, lpfnWinEventProc, idProcess, idThread, dwFlags) 
{ 
   DllCall("CoInitialize", "uint", 0) 
   return DllCall("SetWinEventHook", "uint", eventMin, "uint", eventMax, "uint", hmodWinEventProc, "uint", lpfnWinEventProc, "uint", idProcess, "uint", idThread, "uint", dwFlags) 
}
```

But it's only going to update the child window's position when a window moves, not when when you activate another window.
So you're going to need catch a window getting focus as well.
That can be done by very nicely with a shell hook.
I'll just explain this with comments in the code, and here are the relevant documentation links:
[RegisterShellHookWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registershellhookwindow), [RegisterWindowMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerwindowmessagea), [OnMessage](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/OnMessage.htm)

```
;register our script to receive shell messages
DllCall("RegisterShellHookWindow", UInt, ChildhWnd)

;define a unique message which we'll monitor
MsgId := DllCall("RegisterWindowMessage", Str, "SHELLHOOK")

;monitors the the message and fires the our 
;user defined function "MsgMonitor"
OnMessage(MsgId, "MsgMonitor")

MsgMonitor(wParam, lParam) ;wParam = message, lParam = hwnd
{
    ;HSHELL_WINDOWACTIVATED = 0x04
    ;HSHELL_RUDEAPPACTIVATED = 0x8004
    if (wParam = 0x8004 || wParam = 0x8004) 
        ;we can borrow the HookProc function so we dont
        ;need to type the same code again
        ;first two parameters arent needed
        HookProc("whatever", "whatever", lParam)
}
```

---

> ## And now finally you should arrive at a finished product like this:

```
SetWinDelay, -1

hookProcAdr := RegisterCallback("HookProc")
hHook := SetWinEventHook(0x800B,0x800B,0,hookProcAdr,0,0,0) ; EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE 

Gui, +hwndChildhWnd +AlwaysOnTop
Gui, add, text, , % "some text in a small gui that will move around with a notepad window"
Gui, add, Button, , Button

;register our script to receive shell messages
DllCall("RegisterShellHookWindow", UInt, ChildhWnd)
;define a unique message which we'll monitor
MsgId := DllCall("RegisterWindowMessage", Str, "SHELLHOOK")
;monitors the the message and fires the our 
;user defined function "MsgMonitor"
OnMessage(MsgId, "MsgMonitor")

MainhWnd := WinExist("A")

ChildWindowWidthHalf := 349/2

WinGetPos, mX, mY, mW, , % "ahk_id " MainhWnd
offset2 := (mw / 2) - ChildWindowWidthHalf

cX := mX + offset2
cY := mY

Gui, show, % "x" cX " y" cY
return

MsgMonitor(wParam, lParam) ;wParam = message, lParam = hwnd
{
    ;HSHELL_WINDOWACTIVATED = 0x04
    ;HSHELL_RUDEAPPACTIVATED = 0x8004
    if (wParam = 0x8004 || wParam = 0x8004) 
        ;we can borrow the HookProc function so we dont
        ;need to type the same code again
        ;first two parameters arent needed
        HookProc("whatever", "whatever", lParam)
}

HookProc(hWinEventHook, event, hwnd) 
{ 
    global ChildhWnd, ChildWindowWidthHalf
    if (hwnd = WinActive("A"))
    {
        WinGetPos, hX, hY, hW, , % "ahk_id " hwnd 
        
        offset1 := (hW / 2) - ChildWindowWidthHalf
        X := hX + offset1
        Y := hY
        
        WinMove, % "ahk_id " ChildhWnd, , % X, % Y
    }
} 

SetWinEventHook(eventMin, eventMax, hmodWinEventProc, lpfnWinEventProc, idProcess, idThread, dwFlags) 
{ 
   DllCall("CoInitialize", "uint", 0) 
   return DllCall("SetWinEventHook", "uint", eventMin, "uint", eventMax, "uint", hmodWinEventProc, "uint", lpfnWinEventProc, "uint", idProcess, "uint", idThread, "uint", dwFlags) 
}
```

Comment: your code works beautifully but i altered my code since when i posted it.